# Tcl Eval , but I'm not sure

Tags: tcl

I have this command , and I can’t change it :

```
proc command1 {} {

    global var_command1

    if {$var_command1 == "" } {
        puts "nothing..."
    } else {
        puts $var_command1
    }
}
```

I would like to send this variable to this command :

```
set myvar 10
set var_command1 "global myvar; Result= \$myvar"
command1
```

and getting this result :

> Result= 10

So I tried the `eval` command :

```
set var_command1 "[eval {global myvar ; [puts "Result= \$myvar"]}]"
```

As I said, this command may not be the right one and also I don’t know if it is possible...

Comment: Your `command1` just prints a string in a global variable... it's not going to evaluate it first.

Comment: "I have this command , and I can’t change it". If you can't change `command1`, then there is no way you can realise what you want, as pointed out by Shawn.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  `set var_command1 "Result=$myvar" ;command1`

Comment: yes @Rakend, but in my proc `command1` , but as @Shawn and @mrcalvin pointed out to me, it is not possible without modifying my proc @Donal Fellows too , the reply was clear , I need to change my procedure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure that you have does not evaluate the contents of that variable. It just reads it (possibly several times) and prints it at most once. You can set the variable to the result of evaluating a script of course, but the evaluation has to be done before that procedure is scanned, at least unless you do something "clever" with read traces. But don't do that; it would just be deeply confusing and very flaky in practice! (It is such a horrible idea that I'm not going to provide a code sample for it. Really don't use traces to do that, as you'll make code you can never debug.)

In general, Tcl is careful to not evaluate code except when directly told to do so, as unexpected evaluation would be a security hole of the very highest order and a source of enormous numbers of bugs and other flaws.

If you want to change the procedure, here is what it should become:

```
proc command1 {} {
    global var_command1
    set result [uplevel 1 $var_command1]
    if {$result eq ""} {
        puts "nothing..."
    } else {
        puts $result
    }
}
```

The change is that it uses `uplevel 1` to evaluate the script in the scope of the caller (`uplevel #0` to always use the global scope would also be viable, given that the script isn't passed as an argument). Also, the `eq` operator is preferred for string comparison over `==`; it doesn't matter too much in this case as the comparison is against a non-number, but using the right operator generates slightly better bytecode.

Comment: Thanks @Donal Fellows ,for giving a detailed answer answer and helping beginners like me , unfortunately I can not change my procedure , but I understand better now the `uplevel` function , thanks for that